# How to optimize a SQL query that aggregates data for individual days over a series of dates?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I'm trying to optimize the below SQL query that returns the count of all products with a specific status on any given day in a series of dates. On any given day, the latest status of the product should be the one given in the query (In the below query snippet it is '2') and there should not be any further status update(s) in that product before that date. The query returns the correct results but it is taking a longer time to run (~ 12 - 15 seconds) if the number of products in a specific store is large and queried for 30 days.

The query takes longer time to run if the number of days queried is more, i.e, it takes only 3 seconds if queried for 7 days, but I have to query for 30 days only.

```
select
statisticDate as date,
(
select
    count(*)
from
    product as p
join product_status_history as psh1 on
    p.id = psh1.product_id
    and psh1.id = (
    select
        min(id)
    from
        product_status_history
    where
        product_id = p.id
        and productstatus_id = 2
    group by
        product_id)
join product_status_history as psh2 on
    p.id = psh2.product_id
    and psh2.id = (
    select
        max(id)
    from
        product_status_history
    where
        product_id = p.id
    group by
        product_id)
where
    p.store_code = 'ABCD123'
    and ((psh2.productstatus_id = 2
    and cast(psh2.created_at as date) <= statisticDate)
    or (psh2.productstatus_id <> 2
    and cast(psh1.created_at as date) <= statisticDate
    and cast(psh2.created_at as date) > statisticDate))) as counter
from
    generate_series(current_date - 30, current_date + 1, '1 day') as statisticDate
order by
    statisticDate desc;
```

Structure of the two tables is as follows

[image: DB structure]

And the query returns results like this

```
Date       - Counter
2019-05-29 - 60
2019-05-28 - 60
2019-05-27 - 111
2019-05-26 - 123
2019-05-25 - 148
2019-05-24 - 234
2019-05-23 - 344
2019-05-22 - 434
2019-05-21 - 339
2019-05-20 - 256
2019-05-19 - 306
2019-05-18 - 392
2019-05-17 - 361
2019-05-16 - 480
2019-05-15 - 406
2019-05-14 - 203
2019-05-13 - 314
2019-05-12 - 396
2019-05-11 - 368
2019-05-10 - 484
2019-05-09 - 420
2019-05-08 - 234
2019-05-07 - 341
2019-05-06 - 204
2019-05-05 - 245
2019-05-04 - 306
2019-05-03 - 408
2019-05-02 - 342
2019-05-01 - 290
2019-04-30 - 272
2019-04-29 - 202
2019-04-28 - 241
```

Answer (score 0):

> "On any given day, the latest status of the product should be
>   the one given in the query (In the below query snippet it is '2') and
>   there should not be any further status update(s) in that product
>   before that date."

This means for date X you only want to count products which have a single history record with `created_at < given_date and productstatus_id = 2`

Your query however is doing other checks.
If I only take into account your description you can use following query:

The `count(psh.id)=1` guarantees there is only one history before the date to verify. 
The `max(psh.product_status_id)=2` verifies of this single history record has the correct status.

```
select statisticDate as date,
 (select count(*)
    from product as p
   where p.store_code = 'ABCD123'
     and exists (select max(product_status_id), count(psh.id)
                   from product_status_history psh
                  where psh.product_id = p.id
                    and psh.created_at < cast((statisticDate + interval '1 day') as text):: timestamp
                  having max(psh.product_status_id) = 2 and count(psh.id) = 1)
                )
from generate_series(current_date - 30, current_date + 1, '1 day') as statisticDate
order by statisticDate desc;
```

I also did casting on the statisticdate instead of the psh.created_at because so a possible index on created_at could be used.